# Secondary Live tiles in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Can we use secondary Live tiles inside the windows phone application, or secondary tiles will always appear on the home screen?

Comment: This is not a real question for Stackoverflow. Did you tried it first? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Yes, i did spend quite more than 2 hours searching for the answer, and could not find any concrete statement. Just needed to make sure. Anyway if this is against your policies, i will be careful next time.

Answer (score 1):

Live Tiles are displayed on the home screen. However you can simulate Live Tiles within your own app by creating your own control or using the `HubTile` from the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

this is something i have figured out.
Live tiles are Shell Controls, means they will only appear at your Shell/HomeScreen(where all tiles are shown) and these cant be treated as UI Controls inside your app. However you can create their replicas as UI/XAML controls very easily and use them inside your application.
Here is the link for sample code on how to create custom tiles as XAML control inside your application

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Windows-Phone-XAML-Create-3707b497